Current Sensors to view peak/ surge current drawn by BLDC motor
I'm using a 24 V BLDC motor with an inbuilt hall current sensor. While running it at different speeds, the motor stalls randomly. I have plotted the data from the current sensor, and there is no difference between the cases when the motor stalls/ doesn't stall.
I have used a current probe to measure the current with a sampling rate of 100 Hz. Here also, there is no difference in the current values.
I have a feeling that the motor stalls due to a sudden spike in current (surge current) which is not captured by the sensors I have presently.
Are there any sensors that can measure these sudden spikes also? That is, a sensor with a high sampling rate?
Hardware Details:

24 V, 16 A Battery
24 V, 150 W BLDC Motor, Nominal current: 3 A, Stall Current: 40 A
EPOS4 Compact 50/15 CAN, digital positioning controller, 15 A, 10 - 50 VDC


100Hz sampling rate is pretty low for this measurement. But your hardware details are missing the most important piece - the BLDC controller you are using

I have edited the post to add the controller details.

Can you explain what you mean by "stall" here? Usually stall means one of two things: The motor is starting up from a full stop, and current is at a maximum (so-called stall current), or the motor "stalls" due to insufficient current to keep it spinning under mechanical load. Random "stalling" would imply loss of current, not a current spike.

The motor stops while running, so I thought the motor is not able to draw the required current (battery is not able to supply it). Since the ratings are all matching, I felt that the reason is surge current being high.
